# How to use OS X HTML Mail signature on iOS Mail

Tags: icloud, macos, mail.app, ios, signature

I am using an HTML signature in my Mail app on OS X for my iCloud mail account. I created this signature following this instruction: http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-make-an-html-signature-in-apple-mail-for-el-capitan-os-x-10-dot-11/

My question is now, is there a way to sync my signature over iCloud to be able to use it on my iOS device? My signature contains links and images. I would like both to appear in my iOS signature, too.

Detailed device information:

I am using a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan) and an iPhone 5s with iOS 9.3.2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apple has made it impossible to include an image in a signature since iOS 9.3 which is totally rediculous. To us as a company this had made us which to Samsung mobiles. We simply can not work without professional signatures as email is such an important part of our business. Apple makes everyone go back to the stoneage with this change.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly easy work-around to this.  It requires that you setup your email signature in your Gmail account online.  You can include an image, which means it gets uploaded to your Google account, with a permanent reference to it.  Once you've setup your signature in Gmail, just send yourself an email from the online account.  Open this email up on your phone.  Now select the content of the email, your signature, and press copy.  Now go to Settings > Mail and add your signature by pasting it into the signature box.  Your image will be included. If you used different font sizes, they will all be the same now, but Bold, Italics, etc. will be kept.  Even links have the URL intact.  When you send a new mail from the phone, you might not see the image in the mail you are composing, but as the URL is present in the underlying HTML code, the receiving party will see your image in your signature.  This method seems to work with iOS 10.2 PB 3.

Comment: You don't specifically need GMail, just web accessible images. AFIK it's always worked this way - we've used server hosted images and the copy and paste method for years… in addition the server hosted graphic allows you to swap in new graphics (using the same file name) for seasonal or other reasons :D